# used async / await still returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

the name in the call function prints the value but in the return value is undefined and the promise is  solved with undefined value, help me to get the value.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('orders_info')
    .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {    
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

                 console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                 console.log(doc.data().items);
                 var doc_id = doc.id;
                 var amount =doc.data().amount;
                 var uid= doc.data().user_uid;
                 var order_id =doc.data().order_id;
                 var schedule=doc.data().schedule;                        

                 const name =  callus(uid); 
                 console.log(name);  
             });     
        });

//callus function
function callus(uid){
    firebase.firestore().collection('users_info').doc(uid).get().then(async function(doc) {              
        const usr = await doc.data().name;
        console.log(usr);
        return  (usr);  
    });
}
```

Comment: `callus` can't possibly return a value immeidately because it contains an async call.  It will have to return a promise that must be awaited.

Comment: yeah , i have tried `Promise(resolve,reject)` but that returns a undefined value, help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `callus` doesn't return anything. Try this out.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('orders_info')
    .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {    
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

                 console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                 console.log(doc.data().items);
                 var doc_id = doc.id;
                 var amount =doc.data().amount;
                 var uid= doc.data().user_uid;
                 var order_id =doc.data().order_id;
                 var schedule=doc.data().schedule;                        

                 let name;
                 callus(uid).then(res => {name = res}).catch(err => console.log(err))
                 console.log(name);  
             });     
        });

//callus function
function callus(uid){
    return firebase.firestore().collection('users_info').doc(uid).get().then(async function(doc) {              
        const usr = await doc.data().name;
        console.log(usr);
        return  (usr);  
    });
}
```

Try this out..

Comment: it return's 
`Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: "Akash"`
i nedd the value akash , please help me with this

Comment: That's because the call us function returns a promise and it needs to be awaited

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: querySnapshot is not async iterable` the code throws this error.

Comment: Try this out. This must fix it

Comment: that returns a undefined value, i have tried using
`return Promise.resolve(usr);` it also returns undefined value .
the notable thing in console is the console.log in mainfunction prints before the callus() function.

Answer (score 0):

You need your `callus()` function to return a value outside the `.then()`.

If you make it so, the `callus()` function will return a promise that you can await with the `await` keyword:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('orders_info')
    .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {    
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
             console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
             console.log(doc.data().items);
             var doc_id = doc.id;
             var amount =doc.data().amount;
             var uid= doc.data().user_uid;
             var order_id =doc.data().order_id;
             var schedule=doc.data().schedule;                        

             const name = await callus(uid); 
             console.log(name);  
         });     
    });

//callus function
async function callus(uid){
    return firebase.firestore().collection('users_info').doc(uid).get().then(function(doc) {              
        const usr = doc.data().name;
        console.log(usr);
        return usr;  
    });
}
```